# There should be 2 break statements in this infinite while loop

Tags: c#

This is an example from Microsoft socket tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y0e13d3.aspx

I am a bit confused. The first while(true) infinite loop is followed by a second one 4 lines down, yet we only use one break statement. Using break in the second while loop should continue the the first while loop... no?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y0e13d3.aspx

```
while (true) {
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
    // Program is suspended while waiting for an incoming connection.
    Socket handler = listener.Accept();
    data = null;

    // An incoming connection needs to be processed.
    while (true) {
        bytes = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
        data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes,0,bytesRec);
        if (data.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1) {
            break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is only one loop in this example.

Comment: sorry, 2nd one didnt come for some reason. i edited

Comment: ok, this means that the outer loop will just keep running, and so it will keep listening to incoming messages.

Comment: Just FYI, you are missing a brace there. I don't blame you, though. It seems bizarre that Microsoft would not use the defacto standard for braces in C# on MSDN. Threw me off too.

Comment: Therefor I always use the comment 'Loop forever' to show I deliberately doing an infinite loop on purpose. It is not the last time a break statement is missing and an unintended forever loop is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the break statement only exits the inner while loop. That's the point. It's accepting a connection and then reading all data. Until forever.

Answer (score 7):

You are correct. The outer loop in this example is not supposed to exit. This is designed to continually look for new connections. Servers tend to follow this basic pattern.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, `Socket handler = listener.Accept();` is a blocking call that waits for clients to connect.

The outer while loop is just keeping the server alive.  so it doesn't need a `break;`